# Loading SystemC modules dynamically at run-time

Tags: systemc

In my simulator framework, the HW/SW modules are implemented in SystemC and pre-built. The platform to be simulated is described in XML. The simulator core parses the XML, determines the modules used and corresponding libraries files (e.g. dlls in Windows), and loads these modules dynamically at run-time. But I found no sample code of SystemC loading modules dynamically.

How can I do this in SystemC?

Answer (score 1):

Because you said the example in DLLs of Windows, I assume you are doing so in Windows platform. So I suggest you can read the article and example in MSDN [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

If you are using unix platform, you could use `dlopen` and `dlsym` to load the corresponding shared libraries and retrieve the function address to be called from your main program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. While loadLibrary in Windows or dlopen in Linux works for normal C++ libraries, it does not work for SystemC modules. Different SystemC modules dynamically loaded via loadLibrary or dlopen don't share the same SystemC simulation kernel, thus can't be put together in a single simulation framework.

Comment: It's not right. I'm not sure about LoadLibrary on Windows, however, on UNIX, for symbols used in the dynamic lib, they will be looked first from the executable context and other dynamic lib. Finally the symbols in all libraries will be referred to the same one found, except for others using local symbol reference in shared object(SO). That's called weak symbols in the SO. If any strong symbols found, all other weak symbols in the SO will be referred to the strong one. So all function calls in the dynamic libraries can call and use the same object/function in the main executable context.